# From Databricks to Azure Synapse Analytics: when we load a dataframe into table, why do we need to set parquet.writeLegacyFormat as True?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, polybase, azure-synapse

I am in need to load dataframes created in Databricks into Azure Synapse. Now, [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse) requires setting Spark configuration for Parquet as below:

```
spark.conf.set(
"spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat",
"true")
```

Why does it need to be legacy format (i.e. Spark 1.4 <)? Is it mandatory?

*In Databricks, default is False.

- The above statement is per session, so it does not impact other running jobs, but I wonder why we need to use legacy format?
- Would we have alternative way, such as storing as Parquet file (as False), then using Polybase to query ADLSg2?

I should appreciate for your feedback/advices in advance.

<[from Spark 3.0.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)>

If true, data will be written in a way of Spark 1.4 and earlier. For example, decimal values will be written in Apache Parquet's fixed-length byte array format, which other systems such as Apache Hive and Apache Impala use. If false, the newer format in Parquet will be used. For example, decimals will be written in int-based format. If Parquet output is intended for use with systems that do not support this newer format, set to true.

Answer (score 0):

There is legacy model attached to Parquet. ADF & Synapse supports legacy Parquet format as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs-legacy for backward compatibility.

Thanks

Himanshu

Comment: My apology getting back to you late, and thanks for the comment. I will test with the latest Synapse Studio if this is still the case. I would like to use it with latest format  + Delta Lake. I will explore it in August.